# Error in dashboardPage(skin = "red", dashboardHeader(title = "My Dashboard"), : unused argument (skin = "red")

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I tried to create a dashboard using the shinydashboard in rstudio. However the following error appeared when i try to run the app. How to able the dashboard to run without the following error of unused argument: skin = 'red; ? Am i missing library to be installed and called for it to happen?

```
sp <- read.csv("GSPC.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)


   library(shiny)
   library(semantic.dashboard)
   library(shinydashboard)
   library(ggplot2)

   sp$Date = as.Date(sp$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "red",
                
                # Application title
                dashboardHeader(title = "My Dashboard"),
                
                dashboardSidebar("Hello"),  
                
                # Show a plot of the generated distribution
                dashboardBody(
                    frow1 <- fluidRow(  valueBoxOutput("value1")  ,
                                        valueBoxOutput("value2")  ,
                                        valueBoxOutput("value3")),
                    frow2 <- fluidRow(   box(    title = "High"    ,
                                                 status = "primary"    ,
                                                 solidHeader = TRUE     ,
                                                 collapsible = TRUE     ,
                                                 plotOutput("highPlot", height = "300px")  )  ,
                                         box(    title = "Low"    ,
                                                 status = "primary"    ,
                                                 solidHeader = TRUE     ,
                                                 collapsible = TRUE     ,
                                                 plotOutput("lowPlot", height = "300px")  ),
                                         # combine the two fluid rows to make the bodybody <- dashboardBody(frow1, frow2)
                                         
                                         box(    title = "Close Graph"    ,
                                                 status = "primary"    ,
                                                 solidHeader = TRUE     ,
                                                 collapsible = TRUE     ,
                                                 plotOutput("distPlot"),
                                                 width = 9),
                                         
                                         box(selectInput("features", "Features:",
                                                         c("High", "Low", "Open","Close"))), width = 4,
                                         
                                         #dateRangeInput("dates", "Date range",
                                         #             c("Date", start = "1927/12/31", end = as.character(Sys.Date()) )),
                                         
                                         #start = "1927/12/31", end = as.character(Sys.Date())),
                                         
                                         
                                         
                                         
                    )
                ))

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    plot(sp$Date, sp[[input$features]],
         xlab = "Date", ylab = "Feature", col = 'brown', type = "l")
    
})


output$highPlot <- renderPlot({
    hist(sp$High,
         main = "Histogram of High",
         col="purple",
         border="white",)
})

output$lowPlot <- renderPlot({
    hist(sp$Low,
         main = "Histogram of Low",
         col="chocolate",
         border="brown",)
})}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I was struggling with the same issue. I solved it by just not loading "semantic.dashboard". Just delete `library(semantic.dashboard)`. There seems to be a compatibility issue.